# Smooth bijection and tangent spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth bijection between manifolds with same dimension. Do we necessarily have

$$df_p(T_pM)=T_{f(p)}N.$$

I think it is probably not true. But I can't give a counterexample...

Comment: Is this question the same as "Are smooth bijections of manifolds of the same dimension submersions?" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f:x\mapsto x^3$ is a smooth bijection but $df_0(T_0\mathbb{R}) = 0\neq T_{f(0)}\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is this question the same as "Are smooth bijections of manifolds of the same dimension submersions?" please?

Comment: @SeleneAuckland Let me answer your question with a question: is the function $f$ in my answer a smooth bijection between two manifolds of the same dimension that is not a submersion? :)

Comment: Thanks. I guess, yes that $f$ is such. I was just wondering why OP didn't use the word "submersion". So it is the same question then?

Answer (score 1):

How about $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x^3$? Certainly smooth, certainly bijective.  However, $df_0$ will map the $1$-dimensional tangent space to a point.  The root issue is that a smooth bijection can still have critical points.